# While Converting the statement still gets an error Error Converting datatype varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  
    (CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(T.UploadTradePrice) = 1 
           THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(24, 8), T.UploadTradePrice) 
     END) AS TradePrice
FROM 
    dbo.trnUploadTrades T
```

I have 5051 records in this table, `UploadTradePrice`'s datatype is `varchar`.

When executing this query, we get an error message

> Error Converting datatype varchar to numeric

Answer (score 2):

Just use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(24, 8), T.UploadTradePrice) AS TradePrice
FROM dbo.trnUploadTrades T;
```

One example of values that fail are exponential values:

```
select val, isnumeric(val), try_convert(numeric(10, 2), val)
from (values ('123'), ('abc'), ('1e3')) v(val)
```

EDIT:

The question was originally tagged SQL Server 2012, where `TRY_CONVERT()` is the right answer.  In earlier versions, you can try:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(T.UploadTradePrice) = 1 AND
                  T.UploadTradePrice NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND
                  T.UploadTradePrice NOT LIKE '%.%.%'
             THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(24, 8), T.UploadTradePrice) 
        END) AS TradePrice
FROM dbo.trnUploadTrades T
```

Comment: I dont want to use try_convert its prompt an error message as ''NUMERIC' is not a recognized built-in function name.'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a case statement why not put your test for the numeric in the where clause, also its good practice to include the else clause of the case statement.

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(24, 8), T.UploadTradePrice)  AS TradePrice
FROM dbo.trnUploadTrades T
WHERE ISNUMERIC(T.UploadTradePrice) = 1
```